# How to insert a piece of code programmatically using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm learning jQuery and I'd like to use it to solve an old problem that I get. I'd like to use jQuery to add a piece of HTML code programmatically. What I need to do is: create a jQuery function that "parses" all elements/objects that are inside a `div`. When my function get a `img` object, then I'd like to put the `img` inside another `div`.

**To make the things clear, let's suppose that my function parses this piece of code**:

```
<div class="entry">
<img height="200" width="300" src="image-2.jpg" title="my image 1" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-25">
<em>This is my image!</em>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam sit amet elit vitae arcu interdum ullamcorper.</p>

<img height="400" width="250" src="image-2.jpg" title="my image 2" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-25">
<em>This is another image!</em>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam sit amet elit vitae arcu interdum ullamcorper.</p>
</div>
```

**I'd like to write a jQuery function that changes it to**:

```
<div class="entry">
<div class="main-image">
    <img height="100" width="200" src="image-2.jpg" title="my image 1" class="attachment-single-post-image wp-post-image">
</div>
<em>This is my image!</em>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam sit amet elit vitae arcu interdum ullamcorper.</p>

<div class="main-image">
    <img height="100" width="200" src="image-2.jpg" title="my image 2" class="attachment-single-post-image wp-post-image">
</div>
<em>This is another image!</em>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam sit amet elit vitae arcu interdum ullamcorper.</p>
</div>
```

Then, "basically" what I want to do is:

1. Put all `img` objects between `<div class="main-image">` and `</div>`;
2. Replace the `img`'s class to `attachment-single-post-image wp-post-image`;
3. Replace the `img`s height to `100`;
4. Replace the `img`s width to `300`.

That's it :)

I don't know if my explanation is clear. Unfortunately I'm not a "native" English speaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var searchScope = $('div.entry');

var img = $("img", searchScope)
          .attr("height", 100)
          .attr("width", 300)
          .removeClass()
          .addClass("attachment-single-post-image wp-post-image")
          .wrap("<div class='main-image'></div>")
```